# How to add a keyboard shortcut for a macro in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, vba, macros

I want to add a custom keyboard shortcut for a Macro (to zoom in and out) in MS Excel. It works very well with Word thanks to [this](https://superuser.com/a/859670/1867834) answer, but on Excel (at least with Version 2310 that I'm running) there's no "Normal" in the Visual Basic and no "Keyboard shortcuts: Customize..." button in options -> Customize Ribbon. My question is: Is it possible to do in Excel? and if yes, how?

Thank you very much

PS: I need a custom keyboard shortcut because to write '+' with my keyboard I need 'Shift + 1', so 'Ctrl + +' doesn't work

Comment: You should be able to press Ctrl+Shift+1.

Answer (score 0):

Press `Alt`+`F8` to open macro dialog box. Select the macro for which you want to assign shortcut key and click `Options`. There you can assign a shortcut to the macro.
More detailed answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818047/assign-keyboard-shortcut-to-run-procedure#:%7E:text=In%20excel%20press%20alt%2BF8%20to%20open%20macro%20dialog,you%20can%20assign%20a%20shortcut%20to%20the%20macro.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to locate in your Excel options, Customize ribbon then add Developer mode on right side of list(tick it).
From excel locate new Developer tab and from it select Visual Basic on left side, then in "ThisWorkbook" add;

```
    'https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey
    'http://thecodeforyou.blogspot.com/2013/01/vb-keyascii-values.html

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "+%{Up}", "Sheet1.OpenDBox"
End Sub
```

NOTE: you must edit +%{Up} tu suit your keypress and change
Sheet1.OpenDBox to your desired command. That code is example from my code, for Shift+ArrowUp combination. Follow links for more info.

Comment: For example, in Sheet1 I have;

Function OpenDBox()
    LogInInfo.Show
End Function

and it opens a Form named LogInInfo.